# How to do SAGA if one service is REST API only (not message based)

Tags: microservices, saga

I'm trying to understand SAGA (aka. Process Managers - the exact naming is not part of this question).

All SAGA tutorials says that SAGA (orchestration based) sends messages (commands) and receives (handles) incoming messages, e.g.:

```
SagaStart
Send: MakeStep1
Receive: DoneStep1
Send: MakeStep2
Receive: DoneStep2
SagaDone
```

This make sense if:

- services that takes part in this SAGA are implemented in message driven way
- services knows SAGA's orchestrator incoming message queue (thus in fact are coupled with it, because they **have to know** where to send the result message)

What if there is a service that only exposes REST API? Then it would look like this:

```
SagaStart
result1 = HttpClient.Post(step1url); // 'MakeStep1' done with API call
Send: MakeStep2
Receive: DoneStep2;
SagaDone
```

Such approach looks hardly like SAGA. Does it?

Question is: **Can you have SAGA with services that are API only? How?**

Answer (score 0):

A saga is a stateful long running process that typically includes a state machine definition. Incoming messages for the saga need to identify which state they are intended for and the payload that will be applied as input to the state machine (along with the current state).

As such there is no reason why a saga *could* not be implemented with just a REST API but whether you'd actually want to or not is maybe a better question. There is a lot a message broker and bus will do for you and do better than rolling your own. This stuff is not simple to implement correctly and using the right tools will remove a lot of headache letting you concentrate on business requirements instead of infrastructure and framework.

A simple example; if two messages are received at your endpoint for the same saga state close enough together that the first has not completed execution before the 2nd arrives - how will you handle that? Such asynchronous issues when dealing with state are a key factor.

Issues such as asynchronous behavior, message correlation, state machine definition, state storage and lifetime, error handling, poisonous messages, etc are all good reasons to find a framework that handles this stuff for you. Consider looking at Spring Boot, MassTransit and other similar.

Comment: So in other words, in order to implement SAGA, all SAGA participants must know the Saga's orchestrator incoming-message queue to where they send messages after they complete local transaction. Right?

Comment: Yes. A saga orchestrates several separate transactions - the saga participants as you say. The nice thing about using a message broker is you can forget about the queue itself and simply publish a success/fail event. All services listening for those events will receive them, including the saga that is orchestrating the transactions. So long as the event contains a unique correlating state Id the saga can use that to advance to the next state (either the trigger the next transaction or compensate others). Its another good reason to use a message broker (or at least an event pub/sub) framework.

Comment: I won't agree here. Events published to message broker is (in my opinion) different kind of message from command responses. In Saga pattern, orchestrator COMMANDS what to do, and waits for RESPONSE, which IMO is bit different from an EVENT (e.g. command response will contain Saga CorrelationId, while an event will not).